# Photoshop Script - worked fine if/when dragged and dropped to run, returned error when added to Scripts. Now won't even function on a fresh install

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm often required to stitch together a lot of images with subtle transitions or repetitive patterns, but loading them all into Photomerge and running in a single go was prone to a whole slew of issues (poor alignment, complete omission of images, etc) so I found the best way to go about it was to break it down and run the merge on two images at a time > save them > next two > save them > etc until all images had been paired ..and then the process again on those combined sets to create larger combined sets.. and again and again until only one file remained. Painfully time consuming when the files are 80MP and 16bit tiff, but I did find a batch stitch solution which would combine anything within each respective subfolder of a target folder.

I then hired someone to create a script based on this which would basically do that elimination for me: 12 files in a folder would be paired off and stitched (AB CD EF GH IJ KL) and then it would run it again (ABCD EFGH IJKL) and again (ABCDEFGH IJKL) until only one file remained (ABCDEFGHIJKL). They supplied it with photomerge.jsx and I was instructed to drag/drop into PS, select the target folder, and let it do its thing. And it worked perfectly.

But then I tried to move the script into the scripts menu in PS. Didn't work. Replaced the photomerge.jsx that was in PS with the one supplied - and that didn't work either. Restored the original photomerge.jsx and tried running the script via drag and drop as originally instructed: no luck. Uninstalled PS, reinstalled, tried original functioning script - and the same error is returned.

> ```
> Error 2: folder is undefined. 
> -> errorLog = errorLog.concat(decodeURI(folder));
> ```

From the way that I've seen the script work, two folders (test folder 1, test folder 2) are created within the sub folder and the merges take place in there. The script appears to get through the first merge before crapping out.

The respective section is here:

```js
///merges all files in [fList] and saves the result in [saveLoc]
///the result is every 2 couple images are merged together in [saveLoc]
function photomergeAllFilesAsCouples(fList,saveLoc)
{
    //divide the list into equal sized couple lists
    var subLists = divideIntoSubCouples(fList)
    for(var si = 0; si < subLists.length;si++)
    {
        var subList = subLists[si];
        try 
        {
            // The Photomerge generates an unsaved new document with layers
            if(TEST_MODE)
                open(subList[0])
            else
                photomerge.createPanorama(subList, false);
                
            try{
                if(!TEST_MODE) activeDocument.mergeVisibleLayers();
            } catch(e) {}
        
            var resultFileName = RemoveExtension(subList[0].displayName) + RemoveExtension(subList[1].displayName);
            if(TEST_MODE)
                SaveJPG(saveLoc,resultFileName,1);
            else
                SaveTIFF(saveLoc,resultFileName);

            // close the document without saving 
            activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

            // if we've reached this point without hitting an error then the child folder is considered properly stitched
            numberOfGood = numberOfGood+1;
        } catch (e) {
            errorLog = errorLog.concat("\nUndetermined error on ");
            errorLog = errorLog.concat(decodeURI(folder));
            errorLog = errorLog.concat(" ");
        } // end catch
    } 
}
```

Would anyone be able to advise where this is going so horribly wrong?

Comment: What's the 'same error'? Why do you think this part of the code is relevant? Why wouldn't you contact the script author?

Comment: Have amended original post. Error 2: folder is undefined. Reference points to decideURI line near the bottom.

Comment: a message `folder is undefined` means exactly that. In the snippet you posted there's no definition of `folder` so it's impossible to know why it's undefinded

Comment: https://ghostbin.co/paste/usx567 for context. 

Line 1456

Comment: The script worked for me from the menu without issues, so I guess it's something on your end?

Comment: Worked the first time I ran it on OSX, but not since. Ran into the line errors on a fresh attempt on a W10 PC. 

Did it show up as a second Photomerge... menu option on your end?

Comment: it didn't show any menus except for the log in the end with Success message. You should probably contact the script author.